# When creating a form I'm getting Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, html, forms

I know that when creating the php, if you try to call an index that wasn't defined it will give you the notice from the tile, but I dont know how I can fix it in the way Im trying to create it.
Its very basic code.
The form:

```
        <form action="procesar.php" method="get">
            <p>Su nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"/></p>
            <p>Su e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"/></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="Enviar"/></p> 
        </form>
```

And here is the php:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hola <?php echo $_POST ["nombre"]; ?><br></p>
        <p>El teu e-mail es: <?php echo $_POST ["email"]; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know there are some missing things in the form like the html or head and body, but Im always getting this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aaEY.png

Comment: Do you display the html part only when the user sumbit the form ? And your form has `method="get"` and you use `$_POST`, what if you try `$_GET['nombre']` and `$_GET['email']` ? Or change for `method=post`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the form as a `get` request as opposed to `post`.

In order to access the variables as `$_POST`, you will need to update your method property of your form to `post` as below.

```php
<form action="procesar.php" method="post">

  <p>Su nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"/></p>
  <p>Su e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"/></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="Enviar"/></p> 

</form>
```

This means that the form will send as a `POST` request, instead of a `GET` request to your `action`

Comment: Ok, I tried to change the form as get and it works, but when trying to get it as "$_POST, it doesnt work

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully it makes a bit more sense now

Comment: Sorry if you didn't understood my reply. What I meant is that i changed the method to post, and the echo is like: echo _$POST("nombre", but it gives me the same error

Comment: It should work as `$_POST['nombre']`